# Jenkins pipeline - shell command killed zipping a large directory

Tags: shell, jenkins, zip, jenkins-groovy

I have Jenkins Groovy Pipeline where I am zipping a large directory (around 200 MB). However, shell command is getting killed with errors like:

```
./package-code-to-s3.sh: line 18: 20091 Killed
```

**OR**

```
line x: 28026 Killed
```

OR

```
./package-code-to-s3.sh: line 13:  7162 Killed
```

Following is my Pipeline code for the stage:

```
stage ("Package") {
      sh """#!/bin/bash
      set -e
      echo "Packging"
      chmod +x package-code-to-s3.sh
      ./package-code-to-s3.sh ${S3_BUCKET}

      aws s3 cp packaged.yaml s3://builds/Templates/${env.JOB_NAME}/${env.BUILD_NUMBER}-packaged.yaml

      """ 
    }
```

and following is code for **package-code-to-s3.sh**:

```
     #!/bin/bash
      set -e
      S3_BUCKET_NAME=$1
      FILE_NAME_UUID=`python -c 'import uuid; print str(uuid.uuid1())'`
      echo "UUID: $FILE_NAME_UUID"
      ZIP="`pwd`/$FILE_NAME_UUID"
      echo "ZIP FILE : $ZIP"

      cd .aws-sam/build/LambdaHandlers/
      echo "Executing zip  -fz  -q -r $ZIP"
      nohup zip  -fz  -q -r $ZIP . > log.output 2>&1 &
      ls -las
      cd ../../../
      ls -las
      ls -las 
      mv "$FILE_NAME_UUID.zip" $FILE_NAME_UUID
      CODE_URI="s3://$S3_BUCKET_NAME/$FILE_NAME_UUID"
      aws s3 cp $FILE_NAME_UUID $CODE_URI
```

If I run the same commands from the command line, it works perfectly fine.

To me, this seems to be an issue with either buffer or heap memory OR issue with running zip in the pipeline.

My Jenkins instance has just one job running (this one) and Jenkins machine has enough memory, so, RAM shouldn't be an issue.

Any help/suggestion is appreciated.

## **EDIT**

## *Issue Resolved*

Since there was nothing helpful in logs, and it looked like a memory issue to me. I copied the code of `package-code-to-s3.sh` to my Jenkinsfile package stage, and, restarted my Jenkins instance. Strange it might sound, the issue was resolved for me by doing this.

Thanks

Comment: can you check the logs for that. If it is ubunut it would be in /var/log/syslog or else in /var/log/messages

Comment: @error404 - there was no error logged in /var/log/messages pointing to this issue I was facing. Thanks for your suggestion :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Issue Resolved

Since there was nothing helpful in logs, and it looked like a memory issue to me. 
I tried the following:

- I copied the code of package-code-to-s3.sh to my Jenkinsfile `package
  stage`
- Added Workspace cleanup before checkout (just to ensure a clean workspace)
- Restarted my Jenkins instance (machine).

Strange it might sound, the issue was resolved for me by doing this.